# How does one add an application to the LXDE Panel?

Tags: lxde

How does one add an application to the **[LXDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXDE) Panel**? I'm using version 0.5.8 on Lubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Right click on an existing application shortcut in the panel and you will get a context menu with "`Application Launch Bar Settings`" at the top, this is what you want.
If you do not have any existing shortcuts preset... I do not know.

Answer (score 10):

1) Right click on the panel and select "Add/Remove panel items".

2) Select "Application Launch Bar" in "panel applets" sub menu and click "Add".

3) This pops up a window with options to select items from. Again select "Application Launch Bar" from the options and click "Add".

4) This adds a blank "application launch bar" generally at the right end of the panel. Now click on the blank 'application launch bar". This gives you the 
options to assign the "blank launch bar" to your desired application from the 
application menu. You can add multiple applications to the same "application launch menu".

Answer (score 6):

To edit this configuration manually, you need to edit `~/.config/lxpanel/LXDE/panels/panel`

*Thanks to  Serhii Polishchuk's comment: For Lubuntu, substitute LXDE with Lubuntu:
`~/.config/lxpanel/Lubuntu/panels/panel`*

Here's an example showing my few launch bar items:

```
Plugin {
  type=launchbar
  Config {
    Button {
      id=pcmanfm.desktop
    }
    Button {
      id=menu://applications/Debian/Applications/Terminal Emulators/menu-xdg-X-Debian-Applications-Terminal-Emulators-gnome_terminal.desktop
    }
    Button {
      id=menu://applications/Internet/firefox-esr.desktop
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I'm using *gnome-terminal*. That's exactly why I needed to edit this file manually. `gnome-terminal` is a menu item I can find through LXDE's  menu. But unfortunately it is not visible in the *Application Launch Bar Settings* as described in the other solutions. So I had to put it in there manually and it works fine now.

Comment: This is very helpful answer! In Lubuntu dist, path to file slightly diff ```~/.config/lxpanel/Lubuntu/panels/panel```

Answer (score 1):

See here for how to do it via the command-line-interface (cli): [How can I add applications to the lxpanel application launch bar via cli?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177386/how-can-i-add-applications-to-the-lxpanel-application-launch-bar-via-cli)

For the Raspberry Pi 3, however, the answer is a little bit different, and I will do it using GUI tools too:

For this example let's assume I just installed Shutter (`sudo apt-get install shutter`) and want to put a launcher to Shutter on the panel.

New shortcuts (launchers actually), ex, for apps like Shutter (`sudo apt-get install shutter`), after installing, are found in "/user/share/applications".  *Copy* any you want on the panel from there to "/usr/share/raspi-ui-overrides/applications/" via this command, for example: `sudo cp /user/share/applications/shutter.desktop /usr/share/raspi-ui-overrides/applications/shutter.desktop`

Now, right-click on the panel and go to --> Add/Remove Panel Items --> select "Application Launch Bar" (or add a new one of these if none is on the panel yet) --> Preferences --> find the launcher you want in the right-hand-side (it should be available now that you copied it to the above folder, but you will have to dig through the categories to find it...ex: Shutter is under "Accessories") --> select it and click "Add." Now move it up/down as you see fit in your Application Launch Bar, if applicable, and close everything. Done!

Answer (score 1):

For the lubuntu 18.10, drag and drop from the start menu to the quick launch bar.