# Newly installed applications not appearing in various LXDE dialogs

Tags: raspbian, lxde, applications-database

I've installed some applications via apt.  Here they are in the LXDE menu (note the two IDEs and also the "Graphics" menu are present):

[image: Screenshot showing applications in the LXDE menu]

If I right-click on the Application Launch Bar and select "Application Launch Bar Settings" like so:

[image]

The settings dialog does not have any of the applications I've installed (note also, the "Graphics" category is empty - there is no `+` icon next to it):

[image]

The problem isn't limited to the launch bar settings dialog, either.  If I right-click a PNG image in the file browser and select "Open With...", that dialog is also missing the newly-installed applications (note again the absence of the `+` icon next to the "Graphics" category):

[image]

So:  Why are installed applications not appearing in these dialogs, even though they do appear in the main application menu?  Note that they are present in the applications database directory:

[image]

Environment:  A fresh install of the latest Raspbian and the PIXEL desktop environment (which is essentially just a reskinned LXDE).

---

Note for those who think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177386/how-can-i-add-applications-to-the-lxpanel-application-launch-bar-via-cli):  It isn't.  That other question is asking how to add applications to the launch bar.  I know how to do that.  I am not asking how to do that.  I am asking:  Why is LXDE not showing all of the installed applications in various dialogs which are supposed to list all of the installed applications?

Comment: That other question asks how to add stuff without using the GUI.  I'm asking why isn't the GUI working and how I can fix it?

Comment: That question shows you that normal Application Menu and Application Launch Bar are independent. So there is nothing wrong. It is the expected behaviour that random application would not add himself into the Application Launch Bar. That question give you also one method how to add menu item, but probably you can do it also with settings.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi You've said "but probably you can do it also with settings" - but I **cannot** do it with the settings - that's the point of the question!  Have you bothered to read my question properly?  Can you not see in the screenshot that the settings dialog is open on the right hand side and the applications are not in there?  _Note I'm asking about the settings dialog for the launcher, not the launcher itself._

Comment: I've rewritten the question so it's more obvious what the problem is.